# Error when setting new region for map swift

Tags: swift, mapkit

in my project I want to press on a button which is an address and after doing so it should swap to my mapVC and center the map on the address clicked. 
One of the functions called when the button is pressed is the following:

```
 func adressfunc(){
    let mapvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationVC") as! LocationVC

            CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(self.adresse, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

                if let placemark = placemarks?[0] {
                    let location = placemark.location!
                    print("location", location)
                    mapvc.centerMapOnPin(selectedPin: location)
                 }})

}
```

inside the mapVC I have the function centerMapOnPin :

```
 func centerMapOnPin (selectedPin: CLLocation){
    let newregion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(selectedPin.coordinate, regionRadius, regionRadius)
    print(selectedPin, "pinsel")
    print( newregion)
    map.setRegion(newregion, animated: true)
}
```

Printing the location in both functions proved me that the location data got passed correctly but somehow I get the error at 
 map.setRegion(newregion, animated: true)
that says that it unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional.

I can't understand which of them would be nil.

Comment: `map` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print(map)` in the function `centerMapOnPin`. Maybe `nil` is printed.

```
let mapvc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LocationVC") as! LocationVC
```

At this time `map` has not been loaded yet.

Comment: "none" is printed when I do print(map).

Comment: how can I load the map first then ?

Comment: You should not call centerMapOnPin in adressfunc(). You should call this method in the mapVC’s viewDidLoad.